# Pandas Import multiple csv files into pandas based on the filenames listed in a df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of filenames in a dataframe

```
df['Forward']
```

[Out]:

```
6     305_F_SOL.CSV
8     309_F_SOL.CSV
12    312_F_SOL.CSV
13    325_F_SOL.CSV
```

I want to use read_csv on the files listed in df['Forward'] and keep only the 25th line from the csv and append . That bit is ok, but I'm not sure how to make it loop over all the filenames in the df. It should then add the value of the 25th line in a new column for each filename.

Here's what I have so far:

```
rows_to_keep = [25]

df1 = pd.read_csv(df['Forward'], sep=' , ', engine='python', header=None, index_col=None, skiprows = lambda x: x not in rows_to_keep)
```

Here's an example of what I want it to look like:

```
[Out]:
              Forward          Row 25 value
    6     305_F_SOL.CSV            14.6
    8     309_F_SOL.CSV            14.8
    12    312_F_SOL.CSV            17.2
    13    325_F_SOL.CSV            16.1
```

Comment: I think something like  : `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f..., skiprows=25, nrows=1) for f in df['Forward'].values])` ?

Comment: That's working, brilliant, thanks!